# Deadlock While Batch Update

Tags: java, mysql

During update of records in MySql it throws

> batch update exception in connection rollbackjava.sql.BatchUpdateException: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction.

This is a Sample Batch:

```
[UPDATE CM_CAMPAIGN_EMAIL_LOG SET MAIL_BOUNCE = 1 , 
DESCRIPTION = "over quota" , EVENT="bounce" 
WHERE CONTACT_ID IN( 1372606012,1773400728) AND TEMPLATE_ID = 1638839861 AND CAMPAIGN_ID = 198673431, 
UPDATE CM_CONTACT_DETAILS SET SEND_GRID_BOUNCE = 'Y' ,
SEND_GRID_BOUNCE_REASON = "User's mailbox was unavailable or could not be found or because of incoming policy reasons"  
WHERE EMAIL_IDS = 'marmstrong336@verizon.net', 
UPDATE CM_LEAD_DETAILS SET SEND_GRID_BOUNCE = 'Y' , 
SEND_GRID_BOUNCE_REASON = "User's mailbox was unavailable or could not be found or because of incoming policy reasons"  
WHERE EMAIL_IDS = 'marmstrong336@verizon.net', 
UPDATE CM_CAMPAIGN_EMAIL_LOG SET EVENT="delivered" 
WHERE CONTACT_ID IN( 448520112)  AND TEMPLATE_ID = 1638839861 AND CAMPAIGN_ID = 198673431, 
UPDATE CM_CAMPAIGN_EMAIL_LOG SET EVENT="delivered" 
WHERE CONTACT_ID IN( 1773405252)  AND TEMPLATE_ID = 1638839861 AND CAMPAIGN_ID = 198673431]
```

This is the table Structure of `CM_CAMPAIGN_EMAIL_LOG`

```
| CAMPAIGN_EMAIL_LOG_ID | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| SCHEDULE_ID_ID        | int(11)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| CAMPAIGN_ID           | int(11)          | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| TEMPLATE_ID           | int(11)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| CONTACT_ID            | int(11)          | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| LIST_ID               | varchar(18)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| MAIL_READ             | datetime         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| OPT_OUT               | datetime         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| MAIL_BOUNCE           | int(11)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| URL_VISITED           | datetime         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| MAIL_SENT             | datetime         | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| DESCRIPTION           | text             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| TIME_OPENED           | time             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| LAST_OPENED           | date             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| TIME_LAST_OPENED      | time             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| NO_OF_COUNT           | int(20)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| CC                    | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| BCC                   | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| EVENT                 | varchar(50)      | YES  |     | NULL    |
```

So I wanna know whether `CAMPAIGN_ID (MUL)` caused the Deadlock. If yes then how do I sort my code so that this Deadlock doesn't occur.

This is my code:

```
if(event != null && event.toLowerCase().indexOf("bounce") != -1) 
{
    sqlQuery = "UPDATE CM_CONTACT_DETAILS SET SEND_GRID_BOUNCE = 'Y',
                SEND_GRID_BOUNCE_REASON = \""+reason+"\"  
                WHERE EMAIL_IDS = '"+email+"'";
    batchupdateList.add(sqlQuery);
    sqlQuery = "UPDATE CM_LEAD_DETAILS SET SEND_GRID_BOUNCE = 'Y' ,
                SEND_GRID_BOUNCE_REASON = \""+reason+"\"  
                WHERE EMAIL_IDS = '"+email+"'";
    batchupdateList.add(sqlQuery);
    BounceUtil.addBounceSpamRemarks(contactId,email,"bounce","cm");
} else 
{
    sqlQuery = "UPDATE CM_CAMPAIGN_EMAIL_LOG 
                SET EVENT=\""+event+"\" 
                WHERE CONTACT_ID IN( "+mainId+")  AND TEMPLATE_ID = "
              +templateId.trim()+" AND CAMPAIGN_ID = "+campaignId.trim();
    CommonUtil.updateLastContactedField(contactId,"emailReceived");//ZCUB-20150915-176
    if(event != null && (event.toLowerCase().indexOf("processed") != -1))
    { 
        sqlQuery=sqlQuery+" AND EVENT IS NULL";
    }   
    //Event_Sequence_Issue start
    batchupdateList.add(sqlQuery);
    if(event!=null && event.toLowerCase().indexOf("spam") != -1) 
    {
        sqlQuery = "UPDATE CM_CONTACT_DETAILS SET SEND_GRID_SPAM = 'Y'
                    WHERE EMAIL_IDS = '"+email+"'";
       batchupdateList.add(sqlQuery);
       sqlQuery = "UPDATE CM_LEAD_DETAILS SET SEND_GRID_SPAM = 'Y' 
                   WHERE EMAIL_IDS = '"+email+"'";
       batchupdateList.add(sqlQuery);
       BounceUtil.addBounceSpamRemarks(contactId,email,"spam","cm");
    }
}
```

Comment: A deadlock happens when two transactions are blocking each other because they require something the other transaction has locked. Your code doesn't provide enough information about the rest of the system to answer that. You can check what caused deadlocks by e.g. using `show engine innodb status;`

Comment: What else do i need to provide from my code ??

Comment: If you are lucky, your deadlock happens every time you call this function. You have to look at the result of `show engine innodb status;`, and you have to provide at least this. This will tell you which (at least 2) queries are locking each other. Then you have to check the code these queries are called from, and there will probably be a logic flaw with your transactions. You can post both codeparts here and maybe they are sufficient (although you will probably not find someone willing to analyze your code for free if it gets too complicated or long, but maybe it's an obvious problem). ...

Comment: ... It can be just the code you already posted if you e.g. have triggers in your table, but I cannot tell you that without more information. If you are unlucky, your deadlocks only happen sometimes, then any part of your code can be in conflict, and debugging this is hard. `show engine innodb status;` often, and enable logging. You can try to follow some [general guidelines](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-deadlocks-handling.html). The most important one is: always be prepared to repeat the transaction if a deadlock (or some other error) happens.